# Azure ADAL for Python - model has no attribute 'acquire_token_with_username_password'

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

Giving [Azure ADAL for Python](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python) a try. Getting this error when import adal.

```
import adal
```

Gives error

```
token_response = adal.acquire_token_with_username_password( 
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'acquire_token_with_username_password'
```

I have downloaded most recent code from Github.

The README has sample code that uses `acquire_token_with_username_password` so it should be present.

What am I missing?

```
import adal
token_response = adal.acquire_token_with_username_password(
    'https://login.windows.net/ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_TENANT.onmicrosoft.com',
    'username@ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_TENANT.onmicrosoft.com',
    'password'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and answer, I think the issue was caused by name clashes. Your old script name `adal` was clashed with the directory name of the package `adal` for Python.

It's very similar with the other SO thread [ImportError: cannot import name Session, when using Azure SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781904/importerror-cannot-import-name-session-when-using-azure-sdk/), please see my answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

Got it sorted.

I had created a python file named `adal.py` that I was using to test adal.

Looks like adal module was looking at this file as application file?

After I renamed `adal.py` to `adal_test.py` it and delete its `adal.pyc` file now adal is working as expected.

Comment: It is very simple, still I missed it. Thank you for sharing this answer.